# Convert panda date list to python list of date strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I have a panda date list created from the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
panda_datelist = pd.bdate_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=3).tolist()
```

I would like to convert `panda_datelist` into a python list. It should look something like this;

```
python_datelist_from_panda = ['10/2/2017','10/3/2017','10/4/2017']
```

I am using python v3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
In [4553]: [x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for x in panda_datelist]
Out[4553]: ['10/20/2017', '10/23/2017', '10/24/2017']
```

Or, use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
In [4554]: map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), panda_datelist)
Out[4554]: ['10/20/2017', '10/23/2017', '10/24/2017']
```

But, before converting to list you can actually use [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html)

```
In [4559]: pd.bdate_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=3).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
Out[4559]:
array([u'10/20/2017', u'10/23/2017', u'10/24/2017'],
      dtype='<U10')
```

---

Details

```
In [4555]: panda_datelist
Out[4555]:
[Timestamp('2017-10-20 00:00:00', freq='B'),
 Timestamp('2017-10-23 00:00:00', freq='B'),
 Timestamp('2017-10-24 00:00:00', freq='B')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know `strftime` works for panda. Panda gives me the impression of being a totally different animal from python data structures.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the solution of using map and lambda. They look pretty foreign to me. Is it some kind of functional programming?